# how to query all the children nodes for particular attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following sort of xml structure:

```
<ObjectTemplate>
 <Sections>
   <Section Name="something" Identifier="something">
     <Options>
       <Choice text="something">
         <TextField visibility="private">
```

It's not always like the above though. It could be a direct field under Section:

```
<ObjectTemplate>
     <Sections>
       <Section Name="something" Identifier="something">
          <TextField visiblity="private">
```

Is there a way for me to query all the children of  node for attribute "visibility"?

I have following working code so far just to extract Section from xml:

```
select distinct identifier from (
select 
T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
T.C.value('@Identifier', 'nvarchar(50)') as identifier

from @templatexml tx
cross apply tx.CurrentTemplateXml.nodes('(ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section)') as T(C)
) as temp
```

Comment: Hi, is this question solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care much where exactly `/TextField` nodes reside, here is a very simple solution:

```
declare @t table(
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key,
    XMLData xml not null
);

insert into @t (XMLData)
values
('<ObjectTemplate>
  <Sections>
    <Section Name="something1" Identifier="ident1">
      <Options>
        <Choice text="something">
          <TextField visibility="private" />
        </Choice>
      </Options>
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</ObjectTemplate>')
,('<ObjectTemplate>
  <Sections>
    <Section Name="something2" Identifier="ident2">
      <TextField visibility="public" />
      <TextField visibility="friend" />
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</ObjectTemplate>');

select t.Id,
    s.c.query('.') as [TextField],
    s.c.value('./@visibility', 'varchar(100)') as [Visibility]
from @t t
    cross apply t.XMLData.nodes('//TextField[@visibility]') s(c);
```

Comment: I would take this *to query all the children of node for attribute "visibility"* as a hint, that the OP is searching for the `@visibility` and not for `TextField`. Besides the fact that this might get quite slow with bigger structures if you just use `//*`, I doubt, that the visibility flag without its context it helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally `cross apply` deeper level. Something like this.

```
select distinct identifier from (
select 
T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') as name,
T.C.value('@Identifier', 'nvarchar(50)') as identifier,
V.x.value('@visibility', 'nvarchar(50)') as visibility

from @templatexml tx
cross apply tx.CurrentTemplateXml.nodes('(ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section)') as T(C)
cross apply T.C.nodes('//*[@visibility]') as V(x) -- Correction thnx @Shnugo
) as temp
```

Comment: If you want to go deeper you must use `CROSS APPLY T.C.nodes(...)` rather than do a `CROSS APPLY` down from the root again. `CROSS APPLY` is meant to work on *current-row-base* ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what you want, but you might try something like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,xmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('<ObjectTemplate>
  <Sections>
    <Section Name="something1" Identifier="ident1">
      <Options>
        <Choice text="something">
          <TextField visibility="private" />
        </Choice>
      </Options>
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</ObjectTemplate>')
,('<ObjectTemplate>
  <Sections>
    <Section Name="something2" Identifier="ident2">
      <TextField visibility="private" />
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</ObjectTemplate>');

SELECT tbl.ID
      ,Sec.value('@Name','varchar(max)') AS SectionName
      ,Sec.value('@Identifier','varchar(max)') AS SectionIdentifier
      ,att.value('local-name(../..)','varchar(max)') AS ParentParentNode
      ,att.value('local-name(..)','varchar(max)') AS ParentNode
      ,att.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS AttributeName
      ,att.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS AttributValue
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY tbl.xmlColumn.nodes('/ObjectTemplate/Sections/Section') AS A(Sec)
CROSS APPLY Sec.nodes('//*') AS B(Nd)
CROSS APPLY Nd.nodes('attribute::*[local-name()="visibility"]') AS C(att)
```

The result

```
1   something1  ident1  Choice  TextField   visibility  private
2   something2  ident2  Section TextField   visibility  private
```